# UIWebView ScalesToFit and AspectFit in iOS4

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, uiwebview

I've been trying to display some images from the web in a `UIWebView`. What I've been doing is directly using the `loadRequest:` method on the URL, with `ScalesToFit = YES` and AspectFit mode to make it fit the WebView frame. This works fine on iOS5, but in iOS4 it doesn't. In iOS4 the image appears zoomed out.

[Here's a screenshot of it in iOS5](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/8606/iossimulatorscreenshotm.png)

[And what I get in iOS4](http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/8606/iossimulatorscreenshotm.png)

From what I read, iOS5 comes with an integrated ScrollView, and iOS4 and earlier versions don't. Is it because of that? If it is, how can I accomplish what I'm trying to do? I've tried placing the `UIWebView` inside a `UIScrollView` and setting the `scalesToFit` and AspectView settings, but I'm still getting the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just download the image first? I wrote this function for doing just that:

```
-(void)loadImageFromURL:(NSString*)url{
    [delegate didBeginLoadingFromURL:url];

    NSData * imageData = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] retain];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];  

    if (delegate && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didRecieveImage:FromURL:)]) { //Make sure the delegage still exists and what not ;)
             [delegate didRecieveImage:image FromURL:url];
    }

    [imageData release];
    [image release];
```

}

Comment: Thanks, for the answer and sharing your method :) But I'm trying to use UIWebView because of the integrated zoom and pan capabilities of it, since most of the images are larger than the frame.

Comment: You can put a UIImageView inside of a UIScrollView to get the pan and zoom capabilities, that would be the proper way to do it.